# Is there a way to get rid of dirt patches?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My town has dirt patches all over it.  Sometimes the patches are so large I can't even hide them with flowers.  Is there a way to get rid of the dirt patches or just in general make my town look nicer?

If so, how?

Comment: Something to note in addition to the 2 answers given: the dirt patches that your town started with cannot be "re-grown" (excl. the dirt patches underneath villagers' homes - when they move away, these ones can be regrown)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all *Animal Crossing* games, grass deteriorates from a player character walking over an area, so simply not walking on a dirt area at all will allow it to very slowly regrow grass. In *New Leaf*, this regrow happens in real-time, so time when you're not in the game counts as well.

The rate of regrowth can be doubled by planting flowers on the patch, and watering those plants everyday. However, if you walkover those flowers then the effect will be nullified and the grass will continue to deteriorate. A similar effect occurs with trees, bushes, and even precipitation.

So in summary:

- Don't walk on the deteriorating grass, or patch of dirt, you are trying to remove
- Plants flowers, trees, and bushes on the affected area
- If you plant flowers, water them everyday
- Precipitation counts as well

Comment: Does just *walking* over them reset it? Or do you have to be running?

Answer (score 1):

You can plant flowers over the spots, and then water them every day. Eventually, the grass will replenish itself if you continue to water your flowers over it!

Answer (score -1):

I find it annoying as well. Just plant flowers over the patches and water them everyday and the grass will slowly grow back. Don't walk over them as it will continue to deteriorate again. This will take about 2-4 weeks depending on how much the grass/dirt has deteriorated.